# Auto complete feature on whole web application

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I working on `java web application`. I need to implement auto complete feature on whole site. 
Irrespective of form/application autocomplete should bring all date available in my database(even from outside if possible) .

The **Basic idea** is to make user type less . I know some plugins which implements auto complete, but we have to preprocess data and give on json format and apply on html element .
I am looking for some great tool which reads `(keeps in memory)` whole database and makes some buffer list and gives suggestions whenever user types something on form /input elements .

I am using following technologies :

1. java
2. hibernate
3. spring
4. jquery
5. bootstrap
6. mysql
7. maven

Answer (score 1):

```
... some great tool which reads (keeps in memory) whole database and makes some buffer list and gives suggestions...
```

Believe me, Keeping whole DB into memory is really horrible. But to get better performance, you can always cache the required data and keep that in the memory. This will improve performance as well as make the application simple to configure and maintain.

Look at such a framework - http://lucene.apache.org/core/

Comment: hey Ved thanks for your answer ,"some great tool which reads (keeps in memory) whole database ", I mean to say some list of only string data(collections of words )

Comment: Then its fine. You have to create such a structure which will return data as per your need.